# Integer Division in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I was noticing some wording changes to section 5.6 for C++11. (I'm looking at the draft C++ standard N3242, dated 2011-02-28.) The new (draft) standard includes the sentence:

"For integral operands the / operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded;"

This statement is not in 5.6 of the 03 standard (ISO-IEC-14882-2003), but I don't think this is a change, is it? This is how C and C++ has worked for years unless I've lost my mind (which may have happened anyway).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not going mad.

A footnote to `5.6/4` said:

> `[C++03 footnote 74]:` According to work underway toward the revision
>   of ISO C, the preferred algorithm for integer division follows the
>   rules defined in the ISO Fortran standard, ISO/IEC 1539:1991, in which
>   the quotient is always rounded toward zero.

In C++11 this behaviour is explicitly required rather than being "preferred"; the change is listed in the compatibility section:

> `[C++11: C.2.2]:` 
>   **Change:** Specify rounding for results of integer `/` and `%`
>   **Rationale:** Increase portability, C99 compatibility.
>   **Effect on original feature:** Valid C++ 2003 code that uses integer division
>   rounds the result toward 0 or toward negative infinity, whereas this
>   International Standard always rounds the result toward 0.

Answer (score 2):

Almost.  In C++03 the sign of the remainder for `%` (in which terms both were specified) was unspecified, as such rounding could go away from zero in certain situations too. Compare with the C++03 footnote:

> According to work underway toward the revision of ISO C, the preferred
>   algorithm for integer division follows the rules defined in the ISO
>   Fortran standard, ISO/IEC 1539:1991, in which the quotient is always
>   rounded toward zero.

In practice however, this almost never made any difference.

Comment: This will make a big different in my code. Does this mean that the sign of the result of `%` is also defined now?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: Yes, the whole `/`/`%` thing is now defined to behave the same everywhere. Are you sure it makes a difference in your code? Is your implementation one of the few that does not already truncate?

Comment: There are at least two ways the interpret a modulus operator. The more common way is simply the remainder of division. In this case, the sign of the result is the same as the sign of the quotient. E.g., `-5 % -4 == 1 && -5 % 4 == -1`. Another way is the algebraic way, where the mod operator returns the congruence class of the operand. In this case, `a % m == b` if and only if `m` divides `(b - a)` and is defined where `m` is positive. Here. `b` is a non-negative strictly less than `m`, and so `-5 % 4 == 3`.