# why is elapsedtime giving me an output of 1?

Tags: c++, function, time

```
int elapsedtime(int time1, int time2)
{
int minutes1 = ((time1/100*60)+(time1%100);
int minutes2 = ((time2/100*60)+(time2%100);
return(minutes2-minutes1);
}
```

/******************************************************************************************

```
do
    {
        cout << "What is your starting time? ";
        cin >> time1;
        cout << "What is your ending time? ";
        cin >> time2;

        if (time2>=time1)
        {
        cout << "Your elapsed time is " << elapsedtime <<endl;
        cout << "If you would like to enter other times?(Y/N)" <<endl;
        cin >> choice;
        }
        else
        {
        cout << "Error: Your starting time must be lower than your ending time."<<endl;
        cout << "If you would like to enter other times?(Y/N)" <<endl;
        cin >> choice;
        }
    }
```

I keep getting an output of 1 for every elapsed time?

Comment: [Integer division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617010/integer-division-in-c11) maybe??

Comment: for one you are doing all math as integers which discards fractional parts, eg `3/2 = 1`

Comment: yes i needed to do that in order for me to convert from 24hr time properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
    cout << "Your elapsed time is " << elapsedtime <<endl;
```

Did you mean

```
    cout << "Your elapsed time is " << elapsedtime(time1, time2) <<endl;
```

**Update**

For some reason,

```
    cout << "Your elapsed time is " << elapsedtime <<endl;
```

does not produce a compiler error under g++ 4.7.3 even though the intent is to use `elapsedtime(time1, time2)`.

I was able to successfully compile and build:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int elapsedtime(int time1, int time2)
{
   return 0;
}

int main()
{
   cout << "Your elapsed time is " << elapsedtime <<endl;
}
```

Perhaps another SO post is needed to answer the question, "How does g++ not report error with the above code?".

Comment: Why is there no compilation error - or is the question wrong - I do not see this as an answer?

Comment: R Sahu you are my savior!

Comment: @jquilly1245 Just for the very first resort!! :-/ ... (panic accept)

Comment: @DieterLücking Could it be the OP has a local variable `elapsedtime`?

Comment: I get a [warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/830ecd1e79c51b21) on this. Looks like the function pointer got implicitly converted to `bool`.

Comment: @T.C., It's going on at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530206/how-does-g-not-report-error-with-the-given-code) now. And yeah, they do that, but I'm not sure what the motivation for it was, as I'm pretty sure it's mandated that the result always be `true`.